# Alternative App to run React Native Project

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on React Native Project with EXPO GO app.

EXPO app is crashing every time whenever I test my code. I tried using Android Studio but it is not working properly on my system.

Is there any alternative to run and test my react native app???

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Share the error you are getting

Comment: Protip: if you are having problems with a piece of infrastructure and your code, the problem is *rarely if ever* with the infrastructure. Stick with expo, fix your code.

Comment: There's no error. Before, my code was running properly and when I run it again, it is not giving the same output. I didn't changed the code! But still how it can give different outputs with the same code on expo app? Also EXPO app is crashing again and again...

Comment: what is your android device specification?

Comment: I noticed that expo is working when code is simple but not when its complex! I shifted expo LAN to expo tunnel and my app is working fine (just a little slow to run and see changes)